# Firefox makes links non-clickable

Tags: firefox, security

I am using some online reporting pages from my company's web site. After logging in the related pages, I cannot click on the links that produce the reports. The links seem just as plain texts, and non-clickable. When I open the same pages in ***IE8***, there is **no problem**. The links work and reports are generated. I've looked at the security settings from options menu, but found nothing. How can I make Firefox trust this site and work properly?

Note: The web pages are in *asp* format, and the links are supposed to open the reports in *Crystal Report Viewer*. There are also some *Flash* graphs in some pages, and they don't work either.

Source code of one frame:

```
&lt;SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript"&gt;
    function go_there(url)
    {
        window.open(url + '&prompt0=1&prompt1=' +  [..]);
    }
&lt;/SCRIPT&gt;

[..]

&lt;td style="cursor:hand; [..]"
    onclick="go_there('/webreports/[..]/dpp_zmo_bayi_dd.rpt?apsuser=[..]');">
  &lt;img [..] src="[..]">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Envanter inceleme linki (zmo_bayi_dd)
&lt;/td&gt;
```

After logging into the site, Error Console displays the following errors:

[image: Err1]

[image: Err2]

[image: Err3]

After opening the problematic page, the following errors are displayed:

[image: Err4]

[image: Err5]

Finally, when I click on the links (although they don't look like links), these error messages are created:

[image: Err6]

Comment: Could the problem come from this JavaScript?

Comment: Do you have any FF addon installed like noScript or AdBlock ? which can block scripts or frames ?

Comment: Simple question, to be sure: how is Firefox behaving in general ? Do you use it on sites using javascript, frames, etc ? Typically, SuperUser would display a red "recommendation" on top, if your javascript was disabled, not working, or something.

Comment: I use Firefox all the time with lots of sites and I don't have a problem like this.

Comment: I have AdBlock installed, but I disabled it for company's web site. I also have Greasemonkey and it is disabled as default. I enable it when necessary.

Comment: @mepher, am I right that clicking is in fact possible, even though the mouse pointer doesn't indicate so? If clicking does not work, then what does Tools, Error Console show you?

Comment: As I said, clicking is not possible. It doesn't matter if I hover on or click on the links, they are always shown as plain text. But in IE, I can hover on and see the link target.

Comment: As you're again writing *they are always shown as plain text* -- it's not important *how* things are shown. So, you *did* in fact try to click? And, if nothing happens: what does the error console tell you? (Hovering in IE showing information from the onclick is odd, I think; maybe the HTML source is incomplete after all.)

Comment: Yes I did try to click, and nothing happened. There were no error messages neither. When I double click, it selects the text.

Comment: Too bad! I doubt a popup blocker would be the culprit, as opening the window should be initiated by a click of the user, which is the case here. I did notice that in your source code the first link has no image inside the "TD". That one might be hard to click. The one with the image (which I added above) should be fine though...

Comment: I copied your source code into http://jsbin.com/odowo -- does that work for you? It works in my Firefox and Safari on a Mac. (I disabled the reference to the parent frame, which we don't have here. Maybe that part fails in Firefox with the frames as well? Also please test "Click here to validate you see errors" on that page, just to ensure you actually are notified when a JavaScript error occurs!)

Comment: The page you prepared works on my Firefox. When I click on the link text, it opens a new page in a popup window, and it says: "Hello from JS Bin, This URL does not have any code saved to it". When I click on "Click here to validate you see errors...", nothing happens. But when I open the error console, it says: "Error: parent.detail is undefined, Resource: http://jsbin.com/odowo, Line: 30".

Comment: Ok, all tests passed then, and work as expected. (The text in the popup window is expected as well; I didn't create any additional pages at JS Bin. And you've proven the Error Console works, though the actual error at that JS Bin example is not relevant.) So: there must be some difference when using the real web site (maybe the frames...?), and when using the sample source code. How to find that...

Comment: Tomorrow I'll add the capture of Error Console here. I said there were no errors on the real web site when I click on those links, but I was wrong (I was thinking that: if an error occurs, Firefox would show me immediately). As I opened the error console, I saw some errors. Take care till then, and thanks for your great efforts!

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem, I've added the error console captures.

Comment: Hmmm, new tag `hyperlinks`...?

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem, I thought the problem is related to hyperlinks on the web page, so I've added this tag. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
style="cursor:hand; [..]"
```

The standards for CSS [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp) do not define "hand", and hence that value is [only understood](http://jsbin.com/ezodu) by some browsers (like Internet Explorer, and in Safari if [no strict DOCTYPE is set](http://jsbin.com/ujige)). Firefox doesn't support it.

So: bad design by the creators of the site. However, the CSS only defines how things are *shown*; clicking in [your source code sample](http://jsbin.com/odowo) should still work, even though the mouse pointer might not indicate something is clickable!

```
function go_there(url)
{
    window.open(url
      + '&prompt0=1&prompt1='
      + parent.detail.ust.form1.donem.value, [..]
    );
}
```

```
Error: parent.detail.ust.form1 is undefined  
Error: parent.ust.form1 is undefined
```

Too bad, this is caused by the way the web site tries to get information from the other frames. Maybe the things named "detail" and "ust" just don't exist and Internet Explorer ignores that. Or maybe this is just non-standard, IE-only. Bad implementation.

(I'm sure someone could create a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script to replace the CSS `hand` on the fly, as a workaround. Some script might also fix the bad JavaScript, but as IE works I guess that's a bit too much.)

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Thank you very much indeed, and thanks all friends who tried to help.

Comment: Clicking is possible in IE, but in Firefox it's just plain text with no chance to click on.

Comment: So, it's not solved then...? The CSS does not stop one from clicking. It's just that the mouse pointer does not indicate things are clickable.

Comment: Not solved but I strictly think that the problem comes from the code design. Sorry if I misunderstood as I am not a web design expert.

Comment: The CSS only defines how things are shown; it should not have an effect on how things behave... So, maybe the wrong CSS is the reason why things are shown as non-clickable, but clicking itself is handled by "JavaScript", which looks all right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Source (Right click -> View Source)

Search for the text of one of the links, and see if it has `<a href='url'>The text goes here</a>` sort of tagging. If it doesn't, **firefox is not the problem here**.

Comment: There is no sort of tagging as you stated above. What does it mean?

Comment: I disagree: an image with an onclick javascript trigger can function equally well as a link.

Comment: Indeed it can, however it was clearly stated the link appears as plain text :P

Comment: @Phoshi: but they should still be clickable.

Comment: Yes they should.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the built in popup blocker is being fired. This is a pretty weird way to make a link, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's blocked.

Fx should show a message saying that the popup has been blocked, but you may have clicked a "never show this again" type message at some point... Check the settings to see if you can reset warnings.

Comment: I checked it but popups are allowed. I really don't understand why Firefox behaves like this. The only possibility I can think of is company's web pages are only compatible with IE. I am not, of course, sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing this is a caching problem? How does the URL look like when your at a page where links doesnt work? Firefox will automatically turn the URL into wyciwyg://yourUrlHere.com

You can read more about [What You Cache Is What You Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYCIWYG) and find out how it may affect you.

Comment: The URL looks like normal, in http format.